# Linear independence of $\mathscr{log}$ functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C$ be the vector space of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Are the real valued functions $\{\log_3(x^8), \log_9(3x), \log_4 \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)\}$ linearly dependent or not? Thank you.

Comment: What do $\log_3x^2$ and $\log_9x$ have in common, if anything?

Comment: Look at the first and the last, and think about how one changes base.

Comment: Write them all as logarithms in a common base, expand the expressions using what you know about how $\log$ behaves, and... see what you can see.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can say whether they are not. Question is, do you know what it means to be linearly dependent? Rewrite them as:
$$\frac{8\ln x}{\ln 3}=:u, \frac{\ln 3x}{\ln 9} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 9}=:v, -\frac{\ln x}{\ln 4}=:w$$
Vectors $u,v,w$ are linearly dependent if there exists a non-trivial linear combination that produces the zero vector of that space.
$$k_1u+k_2v+k_3w = 0$$
Find $k_1, k_2, k_3\in\mathbb{R}$ such that at least one of them is non-zero and you will have shown linear dependence.

Comment: We know the requirement of linear indepence ,but how can i find k_1,k_2 and k_3 ?

Comment: You find the basis for the solution:

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at any two vectors of the three. If two vectors are linearly dependent, then the whole system is linearly dependent. A system of one vector is linearly dependent if and only if it's a zero vector, however, so you need not concern yourself with that case.